# How to take derivative of a complicated function with several parameters?

Tags: python, derivative

The following is the code to get CDS spread. 
It is a quite complicated function. 
Is there anyway to take derivative of this function?

It seems that numdifftools doesn't take more than one parameter. 
Also mpmath.diff gave me error such as type unsafe.
Can anyone help on that? Thanks a lot.

```
   1639         cond = cond0 & cond1
   1640         output = zeros(shape(cond), 'd')
-> 1641         place(output, (1-cond0)+np.isnan(x), self.badvalue)
   1642         place(output, cond2, 1.0)
   1643         if any(cond):  # call only if at least 1 entry
```

TypeError: ufunc 'isnan' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''

```
def  CDS(r, R,lamb,sigma,L,S,D,T):
    '''Adjust equity volatility to get asset volatility'''
    sigma=sigma*S/(S+L*D) 
    d=(S+L*D)*exp(pow(lamb,2))/(L*D)
    xi=min(pow(lamb,2)/pow(sigma,2),20)
    zeta=math.sqrt(0.25+2*r/pow(sigma,2))
    '''print("r=%f,xi=%f G(d,zeta,sigma,T+xi)=%f, G(d,zeta,sigma,xi)=%f" %(r,xi,G(d,zeta,sigma,T+xi),G(d,zeta,sigma,xi)))'''
    G_T=pow(d, zeta+1/2)*norm.cdf(-math.log(d)/(sigma*math.sqrt(T))- zeta*sigma*math.sqrt(T))+ pow(d, -zeta+1/2)*norm.cdf(-math.log(d)/(sigma*math.sqrt(T))+zeta*sigma*math.sqrt(T))
    G_xi=pow(d, zeta+1/2)*norm.cdf(-math.log(d)/(sigma*math.sqrt(T))- zeta*sigma*math.sqrt(T))+ pow(d, -zeta+1/2)*norm.cdf(-math.log(d)/(sigma*math.sqrt(T))+zeta*sigma*math.sqrt(T))
    H=math.exp(r*xi)*(G_T-G_xi)
    c=r*(1-R)*(1-SurvProb(d,sigma,lamb,0)+H)/(SurvProb(d,sigma,lamb,0)-SurvProb(d,sigma,lamb,T)*math.exp(-r*T)-H)
    return c
```

Comment: shouldn't you ask this on math.stackexchange?

Comment: If you write out the equation by hand I might be able to solve it.  Otherwise you can approximate a derivative function by successively calling CDS in increments and taking the delta between them as the slope of the tangent line.  It won't be continuous though.

Comment: Thanks. The problem is with norm.cdf function. Something wrong when I took numerical derivative of it by sympy.I wrote the CDF function again. Then, the problem disappeared.